# '||' operators to be used between two enums in a switch statement

Tags: c#, switch-statement, or-operator

I want to check if a function returns either of two enum values, each of the same enumeration type.

For simplicity's sake, I attempted to create a case as follows:

```
case EnumerationTypeExample.TypeA || EnumerationTypeExample.TypeB:
```

Unfortunately, this does not please C#, which says I cannot use an '||' operator despite them being of the same type; strange. Might there be a way this could be done otherwise? An if statement perhaps might work and I may retreat to that, however, I would much rather use a switch statement if possible.

Comment: If, in the back of your mind, you remember OR being used with enums, that's because the bitwise OR (a single pipe character, `|`), is used idiomatically with `[Flags]` enums to combine the bits they represent. The logical OR(two pipe characters, `||`) can only be used with two boolean operators, as you have found out.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A case statement must be constants, not a computation.
However you can use `fall through` in this case:

```
switch (something)
{
    case EnumerationTypeExample.TypeA:
    case EnumerationTypeExample.TypeB:
    {
        DoSomething();   
        break;  
    }
}
```

Now the code will run in both situations.